# I want in one textfield it can be show keyboard and datepicker

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I want show **keyboard** when user click the `button` on the right side and show the `datePicker` when user click the `textField`,

```
@IBAction func doEditBirthDate(_ sender: UITextField) {
    if (txfBirthDate.isEditing){
        btnPhotoIdCard.isHidden = false
        lblPhotoIdCard.isHidden = false
        let mDatePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

        mDatePicker.datePickerMode = .date

        sender.inputView = mDatePicker

        mDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(birthDateChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }else {
        btnPhotoIdCard.isHidden = true
        lblPhotoIdCard.isHidden = true
    }
}

@objc func birthDateChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let mDateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    mDateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    mDateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"

    self.txfBirthDate.text = mDateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
}
```

thats just show date picker but i want add button on the right side text field and if user click it can show keyboard and text it to textfield

I'm sorry for my english

Comment: Can you please upload your code u tried, and images what you want!

Comment: I have not tried it

Comment: You need to add textfield RightView with UIButton , 
For datePicker you need to show picker view on textfield should editing method 
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        <#code#>
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to try this

```
class yourViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate 
{
   var screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bound.height
   var screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bound.width
   var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
   var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem()
   var cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem()
   var timeValueLabel = UIBarButtonItem()
   var datePicker : UIDatePicker!
   var toolBarDtPicker = UIToolbar()


 //MARK:- Life Cycle
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   yourTxtField.delegate = self
  }

 //TextField Editing Begin Function
 func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
 {
    self.hideKeyboard()
    textField.inputView = nil
    textfieldEding(sender: textField)
    return false
 }

 //To Hide Keyboard
 @objc func hideKeyboard()
 {
   UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIApplication.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
 }


 //DatePicker Function
func datePickerView()
{

  if ((self.datePicker != nil) && (self.datePicker.superview != nil))
  {
     datePicker.removeFromSuperview()
  }

  self.datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 
  UIScreen.main.bounds.height-200, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200))
   self.datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

   self.datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateHandler), for: .valueChanged)
   self.view.addSubview(datePicker)

   toolBarDtPicker = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: screenHeight-230, width: screenWidth, height: 30))
   toolBarDtPicker.barStyle = .default
   toolBarDtPicker.isTranslucent = false
   toolBarDtPicker.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
   toolBarDtPicker.sizeToFit()

   // Adding Button ToolBar
   doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneClick))
   let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
   timeValueLabel = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
   let spaceButton2 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
   cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelClick))
   doneButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
   timeValueLabel.tintColor = UIColor.white
   cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
   toolBarDtPicker.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, timeValueLabel, spaceButton2, doneButton], animated: true)
   toolBarDtPicker.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

   self.view.addSubview(toolBarDtPicker)
   self.toolBarDtPicker.isHidden = false

   datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
   dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE dd MMM yyyy"

 }


 @objc func textfieldEding(sender: UITextField)
 {
     datePickerView()
 }

 @IBAction func showKeyBoard(_ sender: UIButton!)
 {        
     self.yourTxtField.becomeFirstResponder()
 }

 //MARK: DatePicker

 @objc func dateHandler(sender: UIDatePicker)
 {
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE dd MMM yyyy"
     timeValueLabel.title = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
 }

 @objc func doneClick() //DatePIcker Done Button
 {
    //Done Button Code
 }

 //MARK: Cancel Btn

 @objc func cancelClick() //DatePIcker Cancel Button
 {
    if ((self.datePicker != nil) && (self.datePicker.superview != nil))
    {
      datePicker.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    toolBarDtPicker.removeFromSuperview()
  }

}
```

Comment: what thats textFieldEding??

Comment: I just added `textFieldEding` function which i forgot to add in answer

Comment: i got error in screenheight-230, screenwidth, and fontColor.defaultblue

Comment: now i updated answer with your above instances try this one